# Having trouble working through an iteration of different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

I am using a for loop to iterate through a list of arrays that all have the same name expect a different number at the end.  For example child1, child2, etc. I though if I tried childi where i is the variable that I would be able to loop through all the arrays.  However, that did not work.  I have change i from an int to a string and concatenating it on the end, but then I get a new variable that is not the same at the array.  Any ideas.

```
        int i=0;
        String []child=childi;//so child would refer to child0 then child1
        for (int j = 0; j < child.length(); j++) {
            Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children.add(curChildMap);
            curChildMap.put(NAME, child[j]);
            curChildMap.put(IS_EVEN, (j % 2 == 0) ? "This child is even" : "This child is odd");
        }   
         i++
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you're trying to do? It's a jumble to me. For instance why create a Map *inside* of the for loop where it will only be discarded and re-created with each iteration of the loop? Makes no sense. I think that it would be much better for you to tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve, not how you're trying to solve it with code, because I'm betting that the correct approach will be significantly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference a variable by a dynamically computed name. In this case your best bet is probably to create an array or other container to hold your child arrays. For example,

```
String[][] children = new String[][] { child0, child1, child2, child3, /* ... */ };
for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  String[] child = children[i];
  for (int j = 0; j < child.length(); j++) {
    Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    children.add(curChildMap);
    curChildMap.put(NAME, child[j]);
    curChildMap.put(IS_EVEN, (j % 2 == 0) ? "This child is even" : "This child is odd");
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the only time I did this was in PHP, which I think is a dynamic langauge

Answer (score 1):

You really won't be able to set the name of the array this way in the code. You're sort of mixing compile-time and run-time options together. By the time your program actually runs, the name of the variable is not only fixed, it's irrelevant--Java really only keeps it around for debugging (and obfuscates can change the name without causing your program to fail).'

To accomplish your ultimate goal, you'll have to put the arrays into another structure, perhaps another array, like this:

```
for (int p; p < people.length(); p++) {
   String[] child = people[p];
   ...
}
```